# tcp connect doesn't work java android

Tags: java, android, tcp, client

I'm new to the network communication and Java programing.
I'm making application (client) on Android which will connect with server on computer. Both programs are connected with the same Wifi network. But I have a problem. When I'm sending message from android client to server, nothing happen. What is wrong?

Android Client

```
try
    {
        Socket s = new Socket("192.168.0.101", 5555);

        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));

        String outMsg = "";
        outMsg = "jakas wiadomosc";
        out.write(outMsg);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        s.close();
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("Error", "something goes wrong");
    }
}
```

and server on computer

```
try
    {
        ServerSocket ss = null;

        ss = new ServerSocket(5555);

        Socket s = ss.accept();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

        String incomingMsg = in.readLine() + System.getProperty("line.separator");
        jTextArea1.setText(incomingMsg);
        System.out.print(incomingMsg);

        in.close();

        s.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.print("not work");
    }
```

Comment: Does anything show up on the logcat?

Comment: Have you write proper permissions in AndroidManifest.xml? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: @Howlin On the logcat I have: 04-04 00:35:26.829: D/Error(9886): something goes wrong
I added internet permission

Comment: @user2374593 that is all that it says?

Comment: yes, it's all that it says when I have filter in my application . But there is much more when is no filter but I think that's a other application on the phone

Comment: @AnubianNoob client doesn't send message to server. That is the problem I think

Comment: There are many many many many many many things that could be going wrong here, it's really hard to help you with such a vague problem.

Comment: @AnubianNoob so what can I tell more? 
I have client on Android (phone Xiaomi MI2S) and server in Java on computer with Windows 8. Both program connect to the same Wifi network (the same router). The code of server and client I wrote above. I think that client can't connect to the server but I don't know why. The IP adress paste in client code is local adress, given by router.

Comment: @user2374593 I really can't tell you more, with networking there are so many things that can possibly go wrong.

Comment: I write exception e to logcat and it says: 04-04 20:08:57.540: D/bład(3162): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Answer (score 0):

I did something that with client program:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class WifiActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wifi);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}

public void buttonGo(View v){
     new PolaczenieWifi(this).execute();
  }



/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pil_oot, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

and create another class PolaczenieWifi with AsyncTask

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class PolaczenieWifi extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

Activity wywolajActivity;

public PolaczenieWifi(Activity wywolajActivity) {
    this.wywolajActivity = wywolajActivity;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
try
{
    Socket s = new Socket("192.168.0.101", 5555);

    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));

    String outMsg = "";
    outMsg = "jakas wiadomosc";
    out.write(outMsg);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    s.close();
}

catch(Exception e)
{
    Log.d("Error", "something goes wrong");
    Log.d("bład", e.toString());
}
return null;
}

}
```

but I don't know that this AsyncTask is write good. In activity_wifi in button section I added `android:onClick="buttonGo"`

The server code doesn't change (made in Netbeans):

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(WifiFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(WifiFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(WifiFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(WifiFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new WifiFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    try
    {
        ServerSocket ss = null;

        ss = new ServerSocket(5555);

        Socket s = ss.accept();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

        String incomingMsg = in.readLine() + System.getProperty("line.separator");
        jTextArea1.setText(incomingMsg);
        System.out.print(incomingMsg);

        in.close();

        s.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.print("Whoops! It didn't work!\n");
        System.out.print(e.toString());
    }
}
```